# How to detect SMS deletion in android?

Tags: android, sms, detect

Is it possible in Android to detect that a message has been deleted from the message store in Android programatically. If yes, do we have access to information that which SMS was deleted.

Answer (score 3):

The best I can think of is that you can register a [`ContentObserver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html) on the SMS/MMS content provider (I think it is `content://mms-sms`) and whenever a change occurs you'll get a callback. Note that you will need to scan the `ContentProvider` and save its current state and then every time there is a change you will need to search the `ContentProvider` to figure out WHAT changed: there is no pre-packaged way to be informed that the user deleted a specific message.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this code

```
try {
        Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
                uriSms,
                new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person",
                        "date", "body" }, "read=0", null, null);

        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                long id = c.getLong(0);
                long threadId = c.getLong(1);
                String address = c.getString(2);
                String body = c.getString(5);
                String date = c.getString(3);
                if (message.equals(body) && address.equals(number)) {
                    // mLogger.logInfo("Deleting SMS with id: " + threadId);
                    context.getContentResolver().delete(
                            Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), "date=?",
                            new String[] { <your date>});
                    Log.e("log>>>", "Delete success.........");
                }
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log>>>", e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is asking how to detect that a delete has occurred. Not how to delete.